# Download an image via firefox extension

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, download, firefox-addon

Im pretty new to writing extensions for firefox, and i now got a problem where i cannot proceed without help:

I want to download an image (open the "save as" dialog) by clicking on a link, and give the saved file a specific name.

How do you do that?